# Misterious MUIWeb Feature

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, feature

In SharePoint Online, as part of the Modern Team site, there is a  **MUIWeb** **Web** feature with the ID 9eabd738-48b1-4a40-a109-aa75458ed7ea. This feature does not exist even in SharePoint 2019.

Does anyone know what this feature is supposed to do? I could not find any documentation describing it. I have checked if this feature exusted as part of a classic Team site and it it's not present there. So I am curious what this does exactly.

This is how I have retrieved this feature:

```
Get-PnPFeature -Scope Web
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MUIWeb** 9eabd738-48b1-4a40-a109-aa75458ed7ea is a hidden feature that is activated by default for the modern sites.

When this feature is **activated**:

- All installed languages are added to the site. In SharePoint Online there are dozens languages available. Note, that these languages are just added to the site, but not actually available yet.
- Multilingual property is set to **true**

[image]

When this feature is **dectivated**:

- Multilingual property is set to **false**. It means that only the default language will be used on this site.

The same can be achieved via code:

```
$web = Get-PnPWeb -Includes IsMultilingual
$web.IsMultilingual = $false
$web.Update()
```

**More details**

The code for this feature is located in the **Microsoft.SharePoint.dll** (SP 2019), in the **MUIWebFeatureReceiver** class.

[image]

**Conclusion**

We can disable this feature on a number of sites to make sure that only default language is used. I don't see any other use cases yet.

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement, with the MUI feature, you can display the following user interface elements in different languages:

- Site title and description
- SharePoint default menus and actions
- Default columns
- Custom columns (list or site)
- Navigation bar links
- Managed metadata services
- Content Editor web part on classic publishing pages

More information:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/office/choose-the-languages-for-a-sharepoint-site-user-interface-16d3a83c-05ab-4b50-8fbb-ff576a3351e8?ui=en-us&rs=en-ie&ad=ie

http://blog.vitalyzhukov.ru/en/cribs/features/16/9eabd738-48b1-4a40-a109-aa75458ed7ea